# Log4j and Jboss. How do I get my log.Debug("Debug") messages to display?

Tags: java, jboss, log4j

I'm trying to start my jBoss server (v4.2) to run and display all of my log.debug messages. I need to achieve this by way of editing jboss configurations. *Not* programmatically through the application.

**my jboss-log4.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<!-- ===================================================================== -->
<!--                                                                       -->
<!--  Log4j Configuration                                                  -->
<!--                                                                       -->
<!-- ===================================================================== -->

<!-- $Id: jboss-log4j.xml 62403 2007-04-18 15:26:43Z dimitris@jboss.org $ -->

<!--
   | For more configuration infromation and examples see the Jakarta Log4j
   | owebsite: http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j
 -->

<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/" debug="false">

   <!-- ================================= -->
   <!-- Preserve messages in a local file -->
   <!-- ================================= -->

   <!-- A time/date based rolling appender -->
   <appender name="FILE" class="org.jboss.logging.appender.DailyRollingFileAppender">
      <errorHandler class="org.jboss.logging.util.OnlyOnceErrorHandler"/>
      <param name="File" value="${jboss.server.log.dir}/server.log"/>
      <param name="Append" value="false"/>

      <!-- Rollover at midnight each day -->
      <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd"/>

      <!-- Rollover at the top of each hour
      <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH"/>
      -->

      <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
         <!-- The default pattern: Date Priority [Category] Message\n -->
         <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p [%c] %m%n"/>

         <!-- The full pattern: Date MS Priority [Category] (Thread:NDC) Message\n
         <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5r %-5p [%c] (%t:%x) %m%n"/>
          -->
      </layout>
   </appender>

   <!-- A size based file rolling appender
   <appender name="FILE" class="org.jboss.logging.appender.RollingFileAppender">
     <errorHandler class="org.jboss.logging.util.OnlyOnceErrorHandler"/>
     <param name="File" value="${jboss.server.log.dir}/server.log"/>
     <param name="Append" value="false"/>
     <param name="MaxFileSize" value="500KB"/>
     <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="1"/>

     <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
       <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p [%c] %m%n"/>
     </layout>      
   </appender>
   -->

   <!-- ============================== -->
   <!-- Append messages to the console -->
   <!-- ============================== -->

   <appender name="CONSOLE" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
      <errorHandler class="org.jboss.logging.util.OnlyOnceErrorHandler"/>
      <param name="Target" value="System.out"/>
      <param name="Threshold" value="DEBUG"/>

      <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
         <!-- The default pattern: Date Priority [Category] Message\n -->
         <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p [%c{1}] %m%n"/>
      </layout>
   </appender>

   <!-- ====================== -->
   <!-- More Appender examples -->
   <!-- ====================== -->

   <!-- Buffer events and log them asynchronously
   <appender name="ASYNC" class="org.apache.log4j.AsyncAppender">
     <errorHandler class="org.jboss.logging.util.OnlyOnceErrorHandler"/>
     <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
     <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
     <appender-ref ref="SMTP"/>
   </appender>
   -->

   <!-- EMail events to an administrator
   <appender name="SMTP" class="org.apache.log4j.net.SMTPAppender">
     <errorHandler class="org.jboss.logging.util.OnlyOnceErrorHandler"/>
     <param name="Threshold" value="ERROR"/>
     <param name="To" value="admin@myhost.domain.com"/>
     <param name="From" value="nobody@myhost.domain.com"/>
     <param name="Subject" value="JBoss Sever Errors"/>
     <param name="SMTPHost" value="localhost"/>
     <param name="BufferSize" value="10"/>
     <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
       <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%d{ABSOLUTE},%c{1}] %m%n"/>
     </layout>
   </appender>
   -->

   <!-- Syslog events
   <appender name="SYSLOG" class="org.apache.log4j.net.SyslogAppender">
     <errorHandler class="org.jboss.logging.util.OnlyOnceErrorHandler"/>
     <param name="Facility" value="LOCAL7"/>
     <param name="FacilityPrinting" value="true"/>
     <param name="SyslogHost" value="localhost"/>
     <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
       <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%d{ABSOLUTE},%c{1}] %m%n"/>
     </layout>
   </appender>
   -->

   <!-- Log events to JMS (requires a topic to be created)
   <appender name="JMS" class="org.apache.log4j.net.JMSAppender">
     <errorHandler class="org.jboss.logging.util.OnlyOnceErrorHandler"/>
     <param name="Threshold" value="ERROR"/>
     <param name="TopicConnectionFactoryBindingName" value="java:/ConnectionFactory"/>
     <param name="TopicBindingName" value="topic/MyErrorsTopic"/>
   </appender>
   -->

   <!-- Log events through SNMP
   <appender name="TRAP_LOG" class="org.apache.log4j.ext.SNMPTrapAppender">
     <errorHandler class="org.jboss.logging.util.OnlyOnceErrorHandler"/>
     <param name="ImplementationClassName" value="org.apache.log4j.ext.JoeSNMPTrapSender"/>
     <param name="ManagementHost" value="127.0.0.1"/>
     <param name="ManagementHostTrapListenPort" value="162"/>
     <param name="EnterpriseOID" value="1.3.6.1.4.1.24.0"/>
     <param name="LocalIPAddress" value="127.0.0.1"/>
     <param name="LocalTrapSendPort" value="161"/>
     <param name="GenericTrapType" value="6"/>
     <param name="SpecificTrapType" value="12345678"/>
     <param name="CommunityString" value="public"/>
     <param name="ForwardStackTraceWithTrap" value="true"/>
     <param name="Threshold" value="DEBUG"/>
     <param name="ApplicationTrapOID" value="1.3.6.1.4.1.24.12.10.22.64"/>
     <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d,%p,[%t],[%c],%m%n"/>
     </layout>
   </appender>
   -->

   <!--  Emit events as JMX notifications
   <appender name="JMX" class="org.jboss.monitor.services.JMXNotificationAppender">
      <errorHandler class="org.jboss.logging.util.OnlyOnceErrorHandler"/>

      <param name="Threshold" value="WARN"/>
      <param name="ObjectName" value="jboss.system:service=Logging,type=JMXNotificationAppender"/>

      <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
         <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p [%c] %m"/>
      </layout>
   </appender>
   -->

   <!-- ================ -->
   <!-- Limit categories -->
   <!-- ================ -->

   <!-- Limit the org.apache category to INFO as its DEBUG is verbose -->
   <category name="org.apache">
      <priority value="DEBUG"/>
   </category>

   <!-- Limit the org.jboss.serial (jboss-serialization) to INFO as its DEBUG is verbose -->
   <category name="org.jboss.serial">
      <priority value="DEBUG"/>
   </category>

   <!-- Limit the org.jgroups category to WARN as its INFO is verbose -->
   <category name="org.jgroups">
      <priority value="DEBUG"/>
   </category>

   <!-- Limit the jacorb category to WARN as its INFO is verbose -->
   <category name="jacorb">
      <priority value="DEBUG"/>
   </category>

   <!-- Limit JBoss categories -->
   <category name="org.jboss">
      <priority value="DEBUG"/>
   </category>


   <!-- Limit the JSR77 categories -->
   <category name="org.jboss.management">
      <priority value="DEBUG"/>
   </category>

   <!-- Enable JBossWS message tracing -->
   <category name="jbossws.SOAPMessage">
    <priority value="TRACE"/>
   </category>


   <!-- Decrease the priority threshold for the org.jboss.varia category
   <category name="org.jboss.varia">
     <priority value="DEBUG"/>
   </category>
   -->

   <!-- Show the evolution of the DataSource pool in the logs [inUse/Available/Max]
   <category name="org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.JBossManagedConnectionPool">
     <priority value="TRACE"/>
   </category>
   -->

   <!--
      | An example of enabling the custom TRACE level priority that is used
      | by the JBoss internals to diagnose low level details. This example
      | turns on TRACE level msgs for the org.jboss.ejb.plugins package and its
      | subpackages. This will produce A LOT of logging output.
      |
      | Note: since jboss AS 4.2.x, the trace level is supported natively by
      | log4j, so although the custom org.jboss.logging.XLevel priority will
      | still work, there is no need to use it. The two examples that follow
      | will both enable trace logging.
   <category name="org.jboss.system">
     <priority value="TRACE" class="org.jboss.logging.XLevel"/>
   </category>
   <category name="org.jboss.ejb.plugins">
     <priority value="TRACE"/>
   </category>
   -->

   <!--
       | Logs these events to SNMP:
           - server starts/stops
           - cluster evolution (node death/startup)
           - When an EJB archive is deployed (and associated verified messages)
           - When an EAR archive is deployed

   <category name="org.jboss.system.server.Server">
     <priority value="INFO" />
     <appender-ref ref="TRAP_LOG"/>
   </category>

   <category name="org.jboss.ha.framework.interfaces.HAPartition.lifecycle">
     <priority value="INFO" />
     <appender-ref ref="TRAP_LOG"/>
   </category>

   <category name="org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer">
     <priority value="ERROR" />
     <appender-ref ref="TRAP_LOG"/>
   </category>

   <category name="org.jboss.ejb.EJBDeployer">
     <priority value="INFO" />
     <appender-ref ref="TRAP_LOG"/>
   </category>

   <category name="org.jboss.deployment.EARDeployer">
     <priority value="INFO" />
     <appender-ref ref="TRAP_LOG"/>
   </category>

   -->

   <!-- ======================= -->
   <!-- Setup the Root category -->
   <!-- ======================= -->

   <root>
      <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
      <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
   </root>

   <!-- Clustering logging -->
   <!-- Uncomment the following to redirect the org.jgroups and
      org.jboss.ha categories to a cluster.log file.

   <appender name="CLUSTER" class="org.jboss.logging.appender.RollingFileAppender">
     <errorHandler class="org.jboss.logging.util.OnlyOnceErrorHandler"/>
     <param name="File" value="${jboss.server.log.dir}/cluster.log"/>
     <param name="Append" value="false"/>
     <param name="MaxFileSize" value="500KB"/>
     <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="1"/>

     <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
       <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p [%c] %m%n"/>
     </layout>
   </appender>
   <category name="org.jgroups">
     <priority value="DEBUG" />
     <appender-ref ref="CLUSTER"/>
   </category>
   <category name="org.jboss.ha">
     <priority value="DEBUG" />
     <appender-ref ref="CLUSTER"/>
   </category>
   -->

</log4j:configuration>
```

**Page I'm testing**

```
private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(ServerLogsController.class
  .getName());

@GET
  @Path("/testDebug")
  public String testDebug(@Context final ServletContext context)
  {
    log.error("This is an error which always shows!");
    log.debug("This is a debug message");

    return "Test Debug Page";
  }
```

Comment: Do you have a `log4j.xml` or `jboss-log4j.xml` file @ your `conf/` folder? You typically edit the log4j xml file to modify debugging levels.

Comment: @cklab This does knock jboss down to debug mode but I still am unable to have my log4j.debug messages display.

Comment: Can you post your `log4j.xml` file?

Comment: @cklab please see the above thread revision for full jboss-log4j.xml. Thanks greatly

Answer (score 3):

There's two ways I can think of to get the debug messages to show here:

**1) You can add a new entry in your xml file for ServerLogsController to display `DEBUG` messages.**

```
<category name="package.for.ServerLogsController">
    <priority value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
    <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
</category>
```

where you replace `package.for.ServerLogsController` with the correct package name. Note that you can also set that to just `package.for` and all files under that directory will log @ `DEBUG` level. This setting will override the root behavior mentioned in the second bullet (i.e. if root is set to `DEBUG` but `package.for.ServerLogsController` is set to `ERROR`, you will not see `DEBUG` messages from `package.for.ServerLogsController`.

**2) Set debugging on the root package**

```
<root>
    <priority value="DEBUG"/>
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
    <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
</root>
```

This will make all packages log at `DEBUG` level unless specifically overriden by a package.

Comment: I appreciate the help. I just tried this, and although I am receiving server debug messages now, I still am unable to get the message in ` log.debug("This is a debug message")` to display

Comment: Which option did you go with? Do you see `This is an error which always shows!`? Which package is `ServerLogsController` in?

Comment: I specified the correct package to the controller and still does not show the debug message. The message "this is an error which always shows!" does display but that isn't the output I'm trying to get.

Comment: See edited answer, might be worth a shot. Is the debug message missing in both appenders (FILE _and_ CONSOLE?)

Comment: I added the the changes you posted above - Still with no luck.I can get log.ERROR messages just not Log.Debug for some reason. I don't know what else I could be doing wrong

Comment: Where are you looking for the debug messages? In the console or the file? Are they missing in both places?

Comment: In both places would be ideal. But at the very least on the console.